# Where-used list of Standard programs

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I'm searching the use of a SAP table. I want to know where the table `S083` is used in SAP standard programs.

I've searched trough the Where-used list. But I only got the self-created programs and not the SAP standard programs.

Anyone know how to search for table use in SAP standard programs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be able to use the where-used functionality for SAP standard coding, the system administrator has to run the program `SAPRSEUB` in order to generate the indices for the programs. This program is a long-run program and also needs some disk space, so be sure that the system has enough hard drive space assigned.

More in SAP Note [401389](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/401389).