# How to find ABAP program/FM which invokes this method?

Tags: class, methods, abap

I am SAP SD module specialist and I often need to debug code. Sometimes I need to know which programs/FM address particular table. I use **Where used** in SE11 for table and it finds the class methods that address this table. But when I use **Where used** for class method the system doesn’t find anything.

Do you know how to find program or FM which invokes this method?

Comment: You should show your work

Comment: I encounter the same problem with interface methods which has no alias in the class. When i go to the interface and use there the "where used" it's working.

Comment: Which method do you mean? Local method in ABAP program? Customer program or standard? Give an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAP Where-used list Standard programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008285/sap-where-used-list-standard-programs)

Answer (score 5):

The Where-Used-Index (WUI) is not guaranteed to be complete for SAP objects on customer systems because it requires a lot of space and time to keep up to date. You can generate it if required by running `SGEN` to ensure a current load is present for all the SAP objects you're interested in, then running `SAPRSEUB` as described in note 28022. Be aware that this program might take days (!) to complete the WUI.

Comment: For information, the reason why the Where-Used List is delivered incomplete (as per SAP decision) is described in the SAP note [401389 - Where-used list in the Workbench as of Release 6.10](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/401389/E).

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use code_scanner or RS_ABAP_SOURCE_SCAN report to search source files that use particular table(s) or method(s).

http://www.saphub.com/abap-general/abap-source-code-scan/

https://www.berater-wiki.de/ABAP_Source-Scan